# SCNView uses OpenGL on iPhone 6 in simulator,

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, metal, pbr

SceneKit uses for SCNView in iPhone 6 on simulator OpenGL,
this causes to changing lightning model from PBR to Phong

> Error: Physically based lighting model is not supported by the OpenGL
> renderer, using Phong instead

Is there a way to fix it?
Newer iPhones render model in SceneKit correctly in PBR

Answer (score 1):

SceneKit uses Metal in the simulator since Xcode 11 running on macOS Catalina. On previous versions of the system only OpenGL was supported.

> In Xcode 11, Simulator adds support for Metal development. You can write iOS and tvOS apps that use Metal and test them in the Simulator, gaining the benefits of hardware acceleration on the Mac during development of your app. If you use frameworks built on top of Metal, such as SceneKit, Core Animation, and UIKit, you'll also see better performance when testing your apps in Simulator.

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/developing_metal_apps_that_run_in_simulator)